# Spin 3 vs spin 2 vs spin 1

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, field-theory, yang-mills, higher-spin

I wanna to understand, why when one gonna to construct interacting theory of spin 3, one need also include infinite tower of spins 4, 5, 6 , ...

As I know, this statement correct even in classical theory.

Why there are not such obstructions for spin 2 and spin 1?

What is fundamental distinction between such theories (spin 3 vs spin 2)?

Comment: I cannont comment on the necessity of including arbitrary high spins for the spin 3 - interaction. As far as I remember, one of the issues of higher spin theories goes as follows : the consistent interaction for spin 1 particles implies the conservation of charge, for spin 2 particles the unified coupling constant, and for the spin 3 the constraints, which lead to Coulomb-like behaviour cannot be resolved. This is so called low-energy Weinberg theorem - https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c869/e99621b446230976eb942ba39d8acc289e0f.pdf?_ga=2.72319891.1242146481.1592496986-890272142.1590143224

Comment: There is some more recent review on that https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.4672.pdf

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator, my question about classical theory. For me, it looks very strange, that spin 3 haven't action which is analog of YM or EH actions. So some deep reason for this must exist!? А так спасибо, Денис:)